# MySQL api workflow

Tags: python, mysql, api

I've never used a MySQL API before. I read about the [oursql](https://code.launchpad.net/oursql) API that is compatible with python3.x and looking at the api I feel a little bit lost. Are there any general guidelines or source code examples about working on a database system? Maybe a cookbook or some sort of documentation? Links to code/documentation and advices that will get me kick-started are very welcome.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of tutorials on using mysql python library. http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqlpythontutorial/

a good general guidline is don't repeat yourself.
additionally there are many tutorials on project management, project directory heirarchies, etc.

If you are creating a web app, there are lots of popular python ones, like django, that will make creating a new project, and working with mysql a breeze.

Comment: Hey I like that link! Thanks. By the way what do you mean by "don't repeat yourself"?